# undefined method `has_key'?

Tags: ruby, hash

When trying to deal with a nested hash in ruby, I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `has_key' for {"_l"=>{"or"=>"@`"}, "a"=>{}}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

isn't the thing referenced by 'for' above... a hash?  don't hashes have the has_key?() method?  what's going on here?

Here's the code... thanks:

```
$conditioning_environments = {
  "_l" =>
   {
    "or" => "@`"
   },
     "a" => {

   }
}
....
if $conditioning_environments["_"+graphemes[index+1]].has_key(g)
    ....
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method you want is [`has_key?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) with a question mark.

The snippet you pasted has the question mark, but error indicates it's missing in the problematic code.

EDIT: you removed the question mark from the pasted snippet :p

Comment: thanks, i guess i assumed that the question mark was optional

Comment: and, you're right, the paste was somehow incorrect(?) and I edited it to reflect what I saw in my code.